# How to download a HTML webpage using Selenium with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to download a webpage using selenium with python. using the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_argument('--save-page-as-mhtml')
d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com")

saveas = ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL)\
         .key_down('s').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).key_up('s')
saveas.perform()
print("done")
```

However the above code isnt working. I am using windows 7.
Is there any by which i can bring up the 'Save as" Dialog box?

Thanks
Karan

Answer (score 32):

You can use below code to download page `HTML`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
  
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com")
with open("/path/to/page_source.html", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(driver.page_source)
```

Just replace `"/path/to/page_source.html"` with desirable path to file and file name

**Update**

If you need to get complete page source (including `CSS`, `JS`, ...), you can use following solution:

```
pip install pyahk # from command line
```

`Python` code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
import ahk

firefox = FirefoxBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe")
from selenium import webdriver

driver = web.Firefox(firefox_binary=firefox)
driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com")
ahk.start()
ahk.ready()
ahk.execute("Send,^s")
ahk.execute("WinWaitActive, Save As,,2")
ahk.execute("WinActivate, Save As")
ahk.execute("Send, C:\\path\\to\\file.htm")
ahk.execute("Send, {Enter}")
```

Comment: Buddy, thanks for the prompt reply. But I am getting the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\karanjuneja\Desktop\Eclipse Workspace\Library\test1.py", line 35, in <module>
    f.write(driver.page_source)
  File "C:\Users\karanjuneja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 106288-106293: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: I want to save the file in .mhtml format.
I used the following code:
    from selenium import webdriver

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com")
    with open("/path/to/page_source.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(driver.page_source)

It saved the page but the page just had source code. Cannot view the original content on the page. Any suggestions?

Comment: You mean you want browser to open your local (downloaded) page copy just like you get it from server directly?

Comment: Yes buddy, just like the webpage appears when we open it.

Comment: :Thanks so much for the answer. Can you please provide the same solution for ChromeDriver as I am using Chrome browser. Would be grateful. :)

Comment: Just replace `driver = web.Firefox(firefox_binary=firefox)` with `driver = web.Chrome()`

Comment: even pyahk didnt work as I have python 3.6 which i think does not support pyahk. Instead I was able to do it with pyautogui, however on clicking CTRL + S to open save as dialog box, sometimes the page is opening the Alt + Space functions. I dont get it why that is happening as the command entered is CTRL "s" only.

Comment: Hm... I use `Python 3.5` + `Win7`. My code works well with `Chrome`. Did you get any exception?

Comment: I dont know, i could not even install pyahk using "pip install pyahk"

Comment: pyahk only for py2. Looks like the source code is gone from bitbucket although there is a fix https://stackoverflow.com/a/44767894/4549682

Comment: What if the website has anti-scrape blockers that block Selenium and BSoup?