# How do imports between different modules packaged by PyPi work?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I have packaged modules `A.py` and `B.py` into a PyPI package `P`. Inside `A.py`, there is a function `a()` which imports a function `b()` from `B.py`. I.e., `A.py` looks like

```
from B import b

def a():
    <some `a` code>
    b()
```

and `B.p` looks like

```
def b():
    <some `b` code>
```

Like I said, both modules were packaged into `P`. I then go to an environment where neither `A.py` nor `B.py` are present, run `pip install P`, and do the following in Python

```
from P.A import a

a()
```

I then get the error `No module named B`.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure that *B.py* was included in *P.whl*?

Comment: `I have packaged modules A.py and B.py into a PyPI package P.` You mean you have python module P where you have A.py and B.py, can you us the directory structure of P?

Comment: `A.py` and `B.py` are initially under the same directory. `P` isn't a module, but rather a pip package (cf. PyPi).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'script'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44764459/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-script)

Comment: `from P.B import b` or `from .B import b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In A.py use import as

`from .B import b`